# newtxmath, libertine, cm figures

Tags: math-mode, libertine, newtx

Newtxmath with `libertine` and `otf` 
is an attractive combination for beautiful mathematics text. But it
is inconsistent in that for figures 0,1,2,...,9 within math mode it uses the CM font,
not the Libertine font.  I understand that there may be size issues, but could not
the Libertine figures scaled up for the math mode?

Comment: Could you please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? If I run `\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage{libertine}`
`\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`
`\begin{document}`
`123 $123$`
`\end{document}`,
all figures are typeset in Libertine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Minimal example:\documentclass{article}\usepackage{libertineotf}\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}123$123$\end{document}
Not only are the figures of different style, they are also of different size.